# renren integration in android

Tags: android, integration

Renren is a famous social networking side of chaina is there any example or Tutorial like Facebook or Twitter integration for integrate my android app with Renren. can someone help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had complete my renren Integration from [here](http://wiki.dev.renren.com/wiki/AndroidSDKCourse)